# Making Hero Unit in Bootstrap match my needs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap, I am trying to make the Hero Unit the full height of the page and then they can click a button and it scrolls down further. I also want some text to display in the Hero Unit at the bottom of the Unit.

I have added: `height: 100%;` and `vertical-align:bottom;` along with: `text-align:center;`

to the Hero Unit in the css file with no avail. It is almost seeming like you can't edit it :(

Here is the full CSS for the Hero Unit Class:

```
    .hero-unit {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 649px;
  padding: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-image: url('../img/blured.jpg');
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
}

.hero-unit h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: inherit;
}

.hero-unit li {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

And the html for the Hero Unit:

```
<!--HERO UNIT -->
        <div class="hero-unit"> 
            <div class="container-fluid"> 
                <div class="row-fluid"> 
                    <div class="span4"> 
                        <h4>The Green Panda</h4> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <p>Professional Web Design</p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4"> 
                        <a href="#professional" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Am I missing something? If so what? I can't figure this out and do not understand why the height: 100% and vertical-align:bottom is not working. Any suggestions are open. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khnz4/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the Hero Unit full height in Bootstrap add this to the `hero-unit` in `bootstrap.css`

```
height: 100%;
max-height:900px;
min-height:630px;
```

To make the items within the `hero-unit` of Bootstrap add this directly above the first `span-4`

```
<div class="span-bottom"> 
    //hero unit items 
</div>
```

And then add the following to your `bootstrap.css` file

```
.span-bottom {
  padding-top: 560px;
}
```

You can name this div class anything you like just be sure to change the name in both the `html` and `css` file!